php curl error handling is not taking effect
This is my php code
<?php

    /* some php code - top */

    /* curl request logic start */

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.abc.com/xyz");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);`
    if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if (isset($error_msg))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . $error_msg;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $response;
    }

    /* curl request logic end */

    /* some php code - bottom */
?>

My problem is , if the server for "https://api.abc.com/xyz" is shut down/is not reachable, the entire php script execution freezes.
What I want is that even if the api "https://api.abc.com/xyz" is down, the php code indicated by  /* some php code - top */ and /* some php code - bottom */ should get executed and the page should not hang/freeze completely.
Any advice would be much appreciated....!
Thank You
I have tried curl error handling, but it does not seem to work.

You can set a timeout to curl connection and reponse request with:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); //connect timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6); //timeout wait response in seconds


<?php

/* some php code - top */

/* curl request logic start */

$ch = curl_init("https://api.abc.com/xyz");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); //connect timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6); //timeout wait response in seconds


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$statuscode=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 
/* according to status code you can code here for instance not equal to 200 */
if ( $statuscode != 200 )
{
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . $error_msg;
}
else
{
    echo $response;
}

/* curl request logic end */

/* some php code - bottom */

?>
Hope this solve your error

You need to set the return value as a string.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Settng timeout worked for me. Thank You all.
